# Return first value in a row that starts with a certain string

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook that calculates some validation criteria on a row-by-row basis. I would like to create a column that gets the first value of a failed criteria, or display nothing if validation passed.
The trouble is, most examples rely on the idea that the data to be found is in a column, not in a row, and for some reason I can't get HLOOKUP to work in this instance.

For example, I have as row headers:

```
ID   Balance   Requests   Failed_LowBalance   Failed_MaxRequestsExceeded
```

And data:

```
0    4.00      4          =IF(B2<10,"Failed: Low Balance","")    =IF(C2>5,"Failed: Max Requests Exceeded","")
```

As shown, column D would only have a value if column B (Balance) is less than ten, and E would have a value if C was greater than five.

Ideally I would just have the first instance where the cells D and E may have a value, and I can emulate that by using a nasty cascading IF statement (ie IF(D2<>"",D2,IF(E2<>"",E2,""))  ), but I'd rather not for obvious reasons.

I tried using HLOOKUP like so, but it doesn't work very well at all:

```
=HLOOKUP("*",D2:E2,1,0)
```

Comment: In the OP, I mentioned an example row, 4.00 for B, and 4 for C, with condition statements in D and E to show a string. ;)
Regardless, It was merely a problem in my HLOOKUP statement, since the condition "*" matches empty cells in addition to those with a value, I just had to put in the prepend text (ie "Failed*").

Comment: Well, each column determines a specific fail condition. The one with the HLOOKUP is supposed to get the first fail, if there is one. You don't really want to use a bunch of nested IF statements, since it quickly becomes unmanagable, especially if there are more than three or so cells to look for the condition. Not only that, but nested IF statements can also be difficult for people to parse when reading through, whereas a single HLOOKUP is much easier to understand. ;)

Comment: Well the end product is actually considering about 20 cells, I just didn't want to confuse the issue and put extra unnecessary fluff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this formula with a wildcard if the string will always start with "Failed"

`=HLOOKUP("Failed*",D2:E2,1,0)`

...and you can add IFERROR function to return some text value if "Failed" doesn't exist, e.g.

`=IFERROR(HLOOKUP("Failed*",D2:E2,1,0),"")`

Comment: Barry, correct me if I am wrong. But what I could understand from the question is... OP wants the row number where both columns are filled up. OP doesn't want to use multiple IFs to find that out... You formula will have to be put in each cell... say in col F...

Comment: Example. `D2` has `Failed...` and `E2` is  blank. `D5` is blank and `E5` has `Failed..` and `D25` and `E25` both have `Failed...` then what I think OP wants is `25`... Maybe I could be wrong with my understanding...

Comment: @Siddarth ... all happens in the same row in the OP's example, and IMHO he wants the column of the first error.

Comment: @MikeD: Then maybe I misunderstood :)

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for, I guess the HLOOKUP was failing because even "*" matches blanks which must have been confusing Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying clear text error messages, you can choose to display numeric values (1, 2, 3, ...) as the meaning is clear via the column headers. Then your first error is the `=MIN(...)` of all error conditions in the row.

On top of that you can have a list of error numbers and clear text descriptions, which provides you with the source of a `=VLOOKUP(...)` besides `=MIN(...)`

Comment: This makes sense, I would create a lookup table with error numbers and lookup from there. The reason I wasn't trying that route was that some of the fails are dynamically written on the sheet (ie with the content of another cell in the row) to provide detail on the fail. The fail columns are more or less expected to be human-readable for clarification if the fail reason was unexpected (ie multiple fails but only the one being shown), which is why I kept it as text instead.